# Pandas DataFrame Numbering based on Previous Numbers in Dataset

Tags: pandas, numpy

My apologies in advance, I wasn't sure how to add the null value to the pandas dataframe, so I placed 'None' in the list.  I have a dataframe that has the following values:

```
None, None, 50,60,70,80,90,None,None, None, 110, None, None

import pandas as pd
number_list = [None, None, 50,60,70,80,90, None, 100, None, None, None, 110, None, None]
df = pd.DataFrame(number_list, columns=['ID'])
```

The ones that have a None need to have a number assigned based on the number before it.  So if the number before the blank value was 90, then the blank number would be assigned a 91 (preceding number +1).  If the None is at the beginning of the line, then the numbering would start with 99901 and so forth.

```
 the final result for this example would be: 
 99901, 99902, 50,60,70,80,90,91,92,93,110,111,112
```

I tried doing this in t-sql, but it is taking over 3 min per batch.  I have several thousand batches...  Any point in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
# getting the group key df.ID.isnull().astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum()  
s=df.groupby(df.ID.isnull().astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)[df.ID.isnull()]
df.fillna((df.ffill().fillna(90000)).add(s,0))
Out[193]:
         ID
0   90001.0
1   90002.0
2      50.0
3      60.0
4      70.0
5      80.0
6      90.0
7      91.0
8     100.0
9     101.0
10    102.0
11    103.0
12    110.0
13    111.0
14    112.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  this worked just as expected.  do you mind explaining how it works?

Comment: @yanci 1st, we fill and fillna () to achieve the steps one , then , 2nd we we handle  the increase by split the df to 2 part isnull and notnull , then we cumcount how many row consecutive

Comment: if I wanted to add by 10 instead of 1,would I just change to .add(10)?  I changed the first line and it worked fine, however first numbers that does not have a proceeding number is still adding by one

Comment: @yanci that should be .mul(10)

Comment: thanks again.  I have one more question for you.  the ones that do not have a proceeding number, i need to start at 990 and then work backwards.  so instead of 90002, and 90001 it would be 980, 990.  The number can't pass 1000, that's why it stars at 990 and goes backwards from there.  so if i have 5 empty slots in the beginning it would be 950,960,970,980,990.  This is only for those first records that do not have a proceeding number.  thanks again for your help!

Comment: @yanci using df.ID.first_valid_index(), to find the first notnull index, then fill value by `990-10*(df.ID.first_valid_index()-1)`

like below `df.fillna((df.ffill().fillna(990-10*(df.ID.first_valid_index()-1))).add(s,0))`